# Convert PDF to image using ImageMagick on command line

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Hi I am trying convert a PDF to an image using ImageMagick and it is throwing the following error:

```
$ convert  error720.pdf  error720.png
convert.exe: FailedToExecuteCommand `"C:/Program Files (x86)/gs/gs9.09/bin/gswin
32c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -
dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsA
lphaBits=4 "-r72x72"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/SURESH~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-
4680NzHfmhYvSbW4%d" "-fC:/Users/SURESH~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4680Wqgv9awWP
WwC" "-fC:/Users/SURESH~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4680KJ2X0fSVMwXJ"' (-1) @ er
ror/utility.c/SystemCommand/2051.
convert.exe: no images defined `error720.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageComm
and/3187.
```

I am running Windows 8 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things you could try:

Check which version of ImageMagick you are using, and which delegates (helpers) are installed. Please run the following commands and click `edit` under your question and then paste in the output.

```
identify -version
```

and

```
configure -list delegates | grep -i delegate
```

Check which version of `ghostscript` you have installed and report:

```
gswin32c -v
```

Try adding a `-density` before reading in your `PDF` file:

```
convert -density 288 error720.pdf  error720.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Mark thanks for the reply. Downloaded the 64 bit version of ghostscript and now it is working fine.

```
Link:
http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/gs910w64.exe
```